# Текущая директория в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как в Python - программе узнать путь до текущей директории со скриптом. Я знаю, что для этого требуется библиотека os, но там столько различных классов и функций, что можно пол дня убить на поиски.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Find current directory and file's directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory

Comment: pwd - отображает текущую рабочую директорию

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Если вы запускаете скрипт `C:\Scripts\script.py` из `D:\work` папки:

```
D:\work> py C:\Scripts\script.py
```

то:

- `D:\work` — это текущая рабочая директория на момент старта скрипта. `open('file.txt')` будет пытаться открыть `D:\work\file.txt` файл
- `C:\Scripts` — это директория со скриптом.

#### Текущая рабочая директория

*Текущая рабочая директория* возвращается [`os.getcwd()` функцией](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd), где `CWD` это Current Working Directory ("текущая рабочая директория"). `os.getcwdb()` возвращает путь в виде байт. Происхождение функции от [POSIX `getcwd(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html). Другие способы могут вернуть разные результаты в зависимости от настроек доступа промежуточных директорий, общей длины (от платформы зависит) итд—не изобретайте своих способов, если не осознаёте всех последствий возможного изменения в поведении функции. Также нетрадиционные способы получения рабочей директории могут ухудшить читаемость другими Питон-программистами. Из [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)
:

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

По умолчанию относительные пути используют именно эту директорию, поэтому ***явно вызывать `os.getcwd()` редко нужно***. Например, `open('file.txt')` вызов открывает файл `'file.txt'` в текущей директории. Если необходимо передать полный путь в виде строки, то можно использовать `os.path.abspath('file.txt')`—`getcwd()` снова явно не используется.

[`Path.cwd()` из `pathlib` модуля](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use) возвращает путь к текущей директории как объект c разными полезными и удобными методами такими как `.glob('**/*.py')`.

#### Директория со скриптом

Текущая рабочая директория может отличаться от *директории с текущим Питон-скриптом*. Часто, но не всегда можно `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` использовать, чтобы получить директорию с текущим Питон скриптом, но это не всегда работает. Посмотрите на [`get_script_dir()` функцию, которая поддерживает более общий случай](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22881871/4279).

Если хочется получить данные из файла, расположенного относительно установленного Питон-модуля, то используйте [`pkgutil.get_data()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_data) или setuptools' [`pkg_resources.resource_string()`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#resourcemanager-api) вместо построения путей c помощью `__file__`. Это работает даже, если [ваш пакет упакован в архив](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5355694/4279). В Python 3.7 появился [`importlib.resources` модуль](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources). К примеру, если у вас есть Питон пакет `data` внутри которого лежит `файл.txt`, то чтобы достать текст:

```
import importlib.resources

text = importlib.resources.read_text('data', 'файл.txt')
```

Если вы хотите найти место куда пользовательские данные можно положить, то [`appdirs` модуль](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/appdirs) предоставляет переносимый способ:

```
import appdirs   # $ pip install appdirs

user_data_dir = appdirs.user_data_dir("Название приложения", "Кто создал")
```

Разные платформы (Windows, MacOS, Linux) используют разные соглашения, `appdirs` позволяет не плодить сущностей и использовать на каждой платформе подходящие директории.

Answer (score 13):

1. Получить текущую директорию, где запущен скрипт

   `dir = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)`
2. Получить текущую директорию, где расположен скрипт

   `os.path.abspath(__file__)`

Comment: Хм, а чем это лучше `os.getcwd()`?

Comment: `getcwd` вынуждает меня помнить расшифровку этого акронима. Лучше бы они назвали это так: `getCurrentDirectory` и даже думать не надо! А мой способ имя `abspath` быстрее намекает про `abs path`, что это если не абсолютный путь? Хорошее имя - меньше боли.

Comment: @sys_dev с другой стороны, одна функция лучше двух

Comment: @approximatenumber, в предложенном варианте функция также одна (`os.curdir` - не функция). С другой стороны, имя `curdir` не сильно лучше `getcwd`, которая, думаю, реализована `return os.curdir`)))

Comment: @approximatenumber: Не экономьте на кол-ве функций экономьте на себе любимом, который придет в какой-нить понедельник "с будуна" и будет пытаться понять код. Надо использовать ЛЮБУЮ возможность Зделать код понятнее ;)

Comment: минус за изобретение велосипеда—подумайте о тех, кто ваш код будет читать. Не нужно своих способов придумывать вместо вызова стандартной функции.

Comment: `getcwd` проще запомнить, поскольку функции с тем же именем применяются и в C и в PHP, и где только еще не

Comment: @jfs: 1. Автор вопрос задал задачу с текущей директорией. Задача решена? Или те способы что я предложил задачу не решают? 2. Ранее в СССР тоже было приняты стандартные вещи что-то вроде ИЖМАШСТРОЙ и это ни к чему хорошему не приводило! 3. Те вещи что я предложил они не стандартны? Чем конкретно?

Answer (score 1):

`os.path.abspath(__file__)` -
возвращает то, что надо - путь до физического расположения файла скрипта.
Но он добавляет в него имя самого скрипта, которое придётся программно откусить чтобы получить именно путь.

`dir = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)` - возвращает вообще ненужную хрень. В винде это будет
`C:\Users\[имяюзера]`

Задача стандартная для работы с файлами, по дефолту лежащими в той же директории, что и скрипт.
Сейчас, как раз, такую решаю.

Comment: Извините, а чем ваш ответ отличается от предложенных ранее ответов, например, [от этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/535324)? Какую новую информацию он несёт?

Comment: Если `dir = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)` у вас возвращает `C:\Users\[имяюзера]`, значит скрипт запущен из этой папки (например, так будет, если вы запустили cmd из этой папки, потом запустили скрипт по полному пути командной `python c:\somedir\script.py`)

Answer (score 0):

Для получения расположения нужной директории с файлом можно использовать это:

```
import os
a = os.path.basename(__file__)
b = os.path.abspath(__file__).replace(a, '')
```

Тогда мы получим путь к директории без названия файла.

Comment: Ваш ответ мало отличается от существующих, а это не приветствуется.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете получить путь к текущей директории с помощью функции os.getcwd из модуля os:

```
import os

current_dir = os.getcwd()
print(current_dir)
```

Этот код выведет путь к текущей директории в консоли. Например, если скрипт находится в папке /home/user/my_project, то на консоль будет выведено /home/user/my_project.

Обратите внимание, что os.getcwd возвращает путь к текущей директории в формате, принятом в вашей операционной системе. На Windows это будет, например, C:\Users\user\my_project, а на Unix-подобных системах (таких как Linux и MacOS) - /home/user/my_project.

Если вам нужно получить не только путь к текущей директории, но и имя файла скрипта, вы можете использовать функцию os.path.realpath из модуля os.path:

```
import os

script_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
print(script_path)
```

Этот код выведет полный путь к файлу скрипта, включая имя файла. Например, если скрипт называется myscript.py и находится в папке /home/user/my_project, то на консоль будет выведено /home/user/my_project/myscript.py.

Обратите внимание, что этот способ работает только внутри скрипта. Если вы запускаете Python интерпретатор из командной строки и хотите узнать путь к текущей директории, вам нужно будет использовать os.getcwd.

Еще один способ получить путь к текущей директории - это использовать модуль pathlib:

```
from pathlib import Path

current_dir = Path.cwd()
print(current_dir)
```

Этот код также выведет путь к текущей директории