# Чтение изображения в Python, библиотека PIL

Tags: python, изображения, pil

Использую библиотеку PIL для чтения изображения, где должен находиться файл с самим изображением?

```
from PIL import Image
pil_im=Image.open('img.jpg')
```

Comment: В текущем каталоге

Comment: В текущем _рабочем_ каталоге.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Текущая директория в Python](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535318/23044)

Comment: @jfs разве это не дубликат?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В той папке где и исполняемый файл

Comment: Это не точно. Папка с исполняемым файлом может отличаться от текущей рабочей директории. [Больше информации можно по ссылке выше прочесть](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535318/23044).

Answer (score 0):

Легче было бы так:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('path/to/file.png')
```