# Python: чтение txt файла из другой папки относительно запускаемого

Tags: python

Есть структура:
A
-testfile.py
B
-textfile.txt

В файле testfile.py нужно считать все данные textfile.txt

Пробовал указать через относительный путь, но не получилось
my_file = open("../b/textfile.txt", "r")

Comment: Что не получилось? Как вы определили, что не получилось?

Comment: При запуске на Jenkins'e выдает
>       my_file = open("../b/textfile.txt", "r")
E       IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../b/textfile.txt'

Comment: Лучше пропишите полный путь.

Comment: К сожалению, использовать абсолютный путь (если вы про него), не представляется возможным.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Текущая директория в Python](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535318/23044) (обратите внимание на `pkgutil` и `pkg_resources` модули)

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно открыть файл относительно запускаемого скрипта, путь к нему можно взять из встроенной переменной `__file__`:

```
import os
print os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'..','b','textfile.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
a = 'dir/dd\er//wq\\qwe'
n = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.normpath(a))
print(n)

with open(os.path.join(n, 'f1'), 'r') as fr, open(os.path.join(n, 'f2'), 'w') as fw:
    fw.write(fr.read())
```

out:

```
C:\Scripts\python\2016\4\dir\dd\er\wq\qwe
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверь `os.chdir`, возможно путь строится изначально не от того пути, который ты подразумеваешь. ну и попробуй построить относительный путь через `os.path.join`