# открыть index.html в новой вкладке firefox

Tags: python, python-3.x, webbrowser

Задача состоит в следующем:
В папке с нашим скриптом есть файл(index.html), и браузер(запихнутый в ярлычок firefox.exe).
Наш скрипт должен открывать фаил в новой вкладке(Именно этого браузера)
**Уже смог сделать это в default браузере**

```
import os  
import webbrowser

new = 2

path = os.getcwd()
file = "file://" + path + "/index.html"
webbrowser.open(file, new = new)
```

Осталось сделать то, что описано выше.
Надеюсь на вашу помощь, заранее спасибо!

Comment: `os.cetcwd()` неверно. Вы вероятно `os.getcwd()` хотели, но лучше [`Path('index.html').resolve().as_uri()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11687478/4279)

Comment: следует заметить, что [текущая рабочая директория  (`os.getcwd()`) и директория, где скрипт лежит (`os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`), могут отличаться](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535318/23044)

Answer (score 3):

```
import webbrowser

# путь к браузеру
ffpath = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe'

webbrowser.register('firefox', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(ffpath), 1)
ff = webbrowser.get('firefox')

# ссылка 
ff.open_new_tab("https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html")
```

Comment: `update_tryorder=1` по умолчанию—можно не передавать явно.

Comment: вы вероятно хотите `update_tryorder=-1`, чтобы ваш браузер использовался впереди других вариантов для `firefox`.

Comment: Да, вы правы. К слову, можно вместо `ff.open_new_tab` использовать `ff.open(url, 2)`