# Вызов python скрипта из С++: вызвать функцию из Питон-модуля, расположенного в одной директории с исполняемым файлом С++

Tags: c++, python, windows, python-3.x, embedded

Приветствую! Стоит задача вызвать функцию из python скрипта documentCreation.py, расположенного в одной директории с исполняемым файлом С++. Код ниже выполняется и в переменную pModule записывается NULL, то есть скрипт не загружается. Предположил, что директория, в которой лежит скрипт не входит в список sys.path, но Py_GetPath() говорит об обратном. Подскажите, как мне импортировать модуль? 
Система windows 10, Python 3.5.2

```
PyObject *pName, *pModule;
Py_Initialize();
pName = PyUnicode_FromString("documentCreation");

pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

//проверяем системные пути python
CStringA myConvertedString(Py_GetPath());
cout << myConvertedString;

if (pModule == NULL)
{
    cout << "import fail";
}
Py_Finalize();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убедитесь, что `import documentCreation` работает вне C++ программы (модуль не выбрасывает ошибки при импорте).

Текущая директория не добавляется в pythonpath автоматически. Это можно сделать, выполнив: `import sys; sys.path.append('')`. Вот `call-function.cc` файл с C++ кодом для примера:

```
#include <Python.h>

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys; sys.path.append('')\n"
                       "import some_module;print(some_module.some_function(3,4))");
    Py_Finalize();
}
```

где `some_function.py` файл в текущей директории содержит:

```
def some_function(a, b):
    return a * b
```

Чтобы собрать исполняемый файл и запустить на Ubuntu:

```
$ g++ call-function.cc -o call-function `pkg-config --cflags --libs python3`
$ ./call-function
12
```

Для Windows, команды следует подправить.

Не обязательно `PyRun_SimpleString()` использовать, можно руками `PyList_Append(sys_path, program_dir)` выполнить, а затем уже `PyImport_Import()` вызывать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Если текущая директория не добавляется в pythonpath автоматически, то почему Py_GetPath(), без добавления чего либо к sys.path,  у меня возвращает строку 

C:\Users\clawf\OneDrive\Source\staff\Win32\Debug\python35_d.zip;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\DLLs\;C:\Users\clawf\OneDrive\Source\staff\Win32\Debug

где последний путь это как раз текущий каталог с исполняемым файлом С++ и импортируемым модулем?

Comment: @Wickedwannabe 1- работает ли как есть код из моего ответа на вашей машине? 2- "откуда X папка в sys.path попадает", когда python embedded—это может быть хороший отдельный вопрос. Создайте минимальный, но *полный* (как в моём ответе) пример кода, запустите его из разных папок, убедитесь что в вашем случае [текущая рабочая директория](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535318/23044) добавляется каждый раз и опубликуйте как новый Stack Overflow вопрос.