# Как вставить изображение в pyqt5?

Tags: python, qt5, pyqt5

Нужно вставить изображение в окне. Везде показан один и тот же способ:

```
label = QLabel(self)
pixmap = QPixmap('image.jpeg')
label.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

Что я, собственно, и сделал, но это не работает.

Вот мой код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, ):
        super().__init__()

        self.resize(1000, 1000)
        self.center()
        self.general()

    def general(self):
        # Menu Bar 
        self.exitAction = QtWidgets.QAction('&Exit', self)
        self.exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(QtWidgets.qApp.quit)
        self.menubar = self.menuBar()
        self.file_menu = self.menubar.addMenu('&File')
        self.file_menu.addAction(self.exitAction)

        self.lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap('img.png')
        self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pix)
        self.lbl.move(200, 200)

    def center(self):
        frame_window = self.frameGeometry()
        center_coord = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        frame_window.moveCenter(center_coord)
        self.move(frame_window.topLeft())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Window()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пробовали указать полный путь?

Comment: да, не помогает, да и картинка в одной папке с исходником, могу также указать на то, что когда мой класс наследовал QWidget, то изображение было ,но только маленькая часть

Comment: @jfs исправил, спасибо за замечание, я тут новичек просто

Comment: @jfs почему-то не отображал png, хотя когда класс наследовал QWidget png отображалось, но не полностью, изменил формат изображения на jpg и в коде это указал, теперь работает.
Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @discoveryone [я проверял](https://gist.github.com/zed/dd33969badf3f37d8062306958fe4667) как jpeg так и png файлы работают (я выше уже упомянул что оба типа работают)

Comment: В моем случае `png` не грузились, как только сменил формат изображения и указал это в `qpixmap`, все заработало.

Comment: @jfs [png] (http://imgur.com/fEtmfPW) 
[jpg] (http://imgur.com/BllUh0o)

Comment: Проверьте с кодом, который я привёл

Answer (score 1):

`setPixmap` это правильный подход, который работает как для png так и jpeg файлов. Вот [пример скрипта, который показывает картинку, переданную в командной строке](https://gist.github.com/zed/dd33969badf3f37d8062306958fe4667):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Usage: view-image <image>"""
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


class ImageViewer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, image_path, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        label = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap(image_path)
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)

        self.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())  # fit window to the image
        self.setWindowTitle('PyQt5 Image Viewer')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        sys.exit(__doc__)
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    image_viewer = ImageViewer(sys.argv[1])
    image_viewer.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Если путь к изображению не абсолютный, то относительные пути, как всегда, ищутся относительно [текущей рабочей директории](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535318/23044).

Если вы хотите показать картинку, которая часть вашего приложения, то в Qt существуют `*.qrc файлы`, где вы [Qt Designer] можете прописать пути. Пример: [python 3 how to put pics inside my program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30047692/4279)

Comment: Странная конструкция с `if len(sys.argv) < 2: sys.exit(__doc__)` зачем она?

Comment: @gil9red: это означает: "если не указаны аргументы в командной строке, напечатать usage (как использовать)" (`__doc__` это docstring для модуля. См. сверху модуля `Usage: view-image <image>` строку)

Comment: Интересная идея :)

Comment: @gil9red: вам тогда возможно [`docopt` модуль понравится](http://docopt.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Вы создаёте `QLabel`, но не указываете ему размер. Попробуте добавить что-то такое в `general`:

```
...
self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pix)
self.lbl.resize(500, 500)  # <--
self.lbl.move(200, 200)
...
```

Ну и проверьте пути, да. Для этого можно вызвать `.isNull()` у созданного `QPixmap`. Вернёт `False`, если такой картинки нет.

```
...
self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap('img.png')
print(self.pix.isNull())
...
```