# Виджет для отображения картинки в PyQt. Как показать картинку из файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Есть ли в qt готовый виджет, чтоб в нем задавалась картинка из файла?

Comment: Вам нужна возможность *выбора* или *показа* из файла?

Comment: Показ картинки из файла

Comment: Попробуйте `QLabel` с HTML-разметкой в свойстве `text`: `<img src="file:///путь_к_картинке" />`.

Comment: похожий вопрос [Как вставить изображение в pyqt5?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/680505/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Тест')
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 300, 300)

    def load_image(self, file_name):
        pixmap = QPixmap(file_name)

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.label.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())

        self.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    ex = App()
    ex.load_image('image.jpg')
    ex.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```