# Ввод имени файла в консоли

Tags: python, консоль

Есть программа, которые берет данные из файла.
При запуске программы в консоле требуется ввести имя файла(файл лежит в одной папке с программой). Но при вводе имени выдает ошибку, что такого файла в папке нет. Это решается вводом полного пути до файла (C:\Users....file.dat). Как можно сделать чтобы требовался ввод только имени файла, без пути. (файл лежит в одной папке с программой)

Comment: import sys
sys.path.append(здесь путь)

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka поясните, что этот код делает и как он поможет?

Comment: sys.path - список путей, где он ищет файлы

Comment: Вы явно не понимаете работу с файлами и модулями в питоне.

Comment: @andreymal это крайне важный комментарий по теме, спасибо

Comment: Лучше бы дали ответ, если понимаете лучше меняю

Comment: По теме нужна точная информация, как и откуда запускается скрипт и где этот скрипт вообще лежит. А sys.path к данной проблеме не отностися вообще никак.

Comment: Вопрос решился таким образом: import os

script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, fileName) 
lines = open(abs_file_path).readlines()

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka, sys.path - список путей, где Python ищет модули, которые можно импортировать через import. Это никак не поможет открыть файл через open.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Текущая директория в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535318/23044) (в секции "Директория со скриптом" упомянуты решения, которые работают и в некоторых крайних случаях таких как: программа в архиве (питон умеет такие модули запускать), программа запущена через symlink (бывает),  программа запущена с помощью `execfile()` (в debugger, IDE, grade tool).

Comment: так же подходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys
import os
```

вариант с указанием полного пути:

```
full_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), filename)
```

или

```
full_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])), filename)
```

вариант с указанием относительного пути:

```
full_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), filename)
```

или

```
full_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), filename)
```

или для Python 3.4+:

```
from pathlib import Path

full_path = Path(sys.argv[0]).parent.joinpath('my_file.txt')
```

или

```
full_path = Path(__file__).parent.joinpath('my_file.txt')
```

или ([спасибо @insolor за подсказку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/727775/%d0%92%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8/727784#comment1101409_727784)):

```
full_path = Path(sys.argv[0]).parent / 'my_file.txt'
```

если нужен полный (абсолютный) путь:

```
full_path = Path(sys.argv[0]).parent.absolute() / 'my_file.txt'
```

**UPDATE:** отличия `__file__` и `sys.argv[0]`:

`__file__` - атрибут, указывающий относительный путь к текущему загруженному модулю/скрипту.

`sys.argv[0]` - относительный путь к главному скрипту, запущенному в OS.

Пример - создадим два файла:

my1.py (модуль который будет импортироваться из основного модуля):

```
import sys

print('my1.py\t__file__:\t{}'.format(__file__))
print('my1.py\tsys.argv[0]:\t{}'.format(sys.argv[0]))
```

m2.py (основной скрипт, который мы запускаем):

```
import sys
import my1

print('my2.py\t__file__:\t{}'.format(__file__))
print('my2.py\tsys.argv[0]:\t{}'.format(sys.argv[0]))
```

Вывод скрипта `m2.py`:

```
my1.py  __file__:       D:\temp\aaa\my1.py
my1.py  sys.argv[0]:    my2.py
my2.py  __file__:       my2.py
my2.py  sys.argv[0]:    my2.py
```

**Вывод:** если использовать `__file__` в функциях из **импортированных** модулей, то мы получим имя данного модуля, а не главного скрипта ...

**UPDATE 2:** бывают случаи когда укзанные выше методы будут работать не совсем правильно - посмотрите следующие связанные вопросы/ответы:

- [Текущая директория в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535318/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-python)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718657/how-to-properly-determine-current-script-directory-in-python/22881871#22881871

Comment: Поясните, что этот код делает и как он помог автору?

Comment: А также в чём разница между `sys.argv[0]` и `__file__` и зачем вы предлагаете оба

Comment: Вместо `joinpath` можно сделать `Path(sys.argv[0]).parent / 'my_file.txt'`

Comment: @insolor, спасибо, добавил в ответ

Comment: @andreymal, добавил описание различий...

Comment: это может сломаться для программы из архива, для скрипта, запущенного через symlink, или через `execfile()`. Посмотрите раздел: [Директория со скриптом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/535531/23044)

Comment: @jfs, вы имеете ввиду вариант с `__file__`?

Comment: Я упомянул три случая. Если не знаете, то попробуйте и убедитесь в каких именно случаях предложенные вами решения не работают. Упомянутые мной случаи совершенно не обязательно поддерживать, если вы понимаете когда решения могут сломаться.

Comment: @jfs, спасибо, попробую когда будет больше времени. А что вы имели ввиду под "для программы из архива"?

Comment: Питон может импортировать, запускать код из архивов (egg, zip, [zipapp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html))

Comment: @jfs, хммм, спасибо - про запуск из архивов не знал...

Comment: Это говорит, что вы не пытались на ссылку «ваш пакет упакован в архив» нажать в моём ответе :)