# как записать файл в определенную директорию ftp

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp

каким образом надо сделать ,чтобы файл который я скачиваю с ftp записывался в конкретную директорию ,а не туда где храниться файл исполнителя?

```
import ftplib
host = "*"
ftp_user = "*"
ftp_password = "*"
filename = "picture.png"
con = ftplib.FTP(host, ftp_user, ftp_password)
lf = open(filename, "wb")
con.retrbinary("RETR " + filename, lf.write)
lf.close()
```

сохранение файла в другую папку 
не так  `C:\Users\\Desktop\try\d` а так `/d`

Comment: Допишите путь к переменной `filename`, что то типа `filename = "dir/nextdir/picture.png"` таким образом файл сохраниться в директорию `dir/nextdir/`

Comment: @Игорь Игоряныч разве filename это не название файла на ftp?

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч  мне нужно не на ftp а с ftp в конкретную директорию на диске

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас filename это и удалённое и локальное имя. Чтобы только локальный путь изменить, чтобы скачать файл в другую директорию, просто явно укажите путь:

```
import os 

with ftplib.FTP(host, *credentials) as ftp, \
     open(os.path.join("директория", filename), "wb") as file:
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + filename, file.write)
```

Comment: а можно как нибудь не полный путь писать а по типу в подпапку корневой папки программы отредактировал вопрос

Comment: да и по сути модер удалил мой подобный ответ написав "Это как-то с ftp связано?"

Comment: @Дмитрий можно. Вместо строки  `"директория"` вы можете и полный путь указать и относительно текущей директории. См. [Текущая директория в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535318/23044). Ваш вопрос по сути к ftp никак не относится: "Как создать файл в указанной папке"