# Где искать файл?

Tags: python-3.x

Если при записи задается только имя файла, где искать этот файл? Как задать полный путь? пример кода:

```
fout = open("relativity", 'wt')
fout.write(poem)
fout.close()
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Текущая директория в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535318/%d0%a2%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Искать файл надо в текущем каталоге программы `os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir)`

```
import os

>>> os.path.curdir
'.'

>>> os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir)
'/home/sa'
```

Задать полный путь можно прямо в имени файла. Для разделения каталогов используйте `os.path.sep`, удобно через `os.path.join()`. Так ваш код не будет зависеть от операционной системы и реализации языка.

```
>>> os.path.sep
'/'

>>> os.path.join('каталог','имя_файла')
'каталог/имя_файла'
```

Для Виндовс допустимо использовать и `\\` и `/`, но лучше везде использовать `os.path.join`

Answer (score 1):

Файл искать в текущем каталоге интерпретатора. Полный путь задается так, например:

```
fout = open("C:\\full\\path\\file.txt", 'wt')
```