# Как открыть файл из родительской директории выполняемого скрипта?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Структура такова:

```
[mydir]: script.py
resources.txt
```

Надо из скрипта script.py открыть файл resources.py.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Текущая директория в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535318/23044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто открыть файл из родительского каталога?

```
with open('../file.txt', 'r') as read_file:
    read_file.read()
```

Comment: это работает только если запустить скрипт из директории, содержащей script.py. Чтобы можно было из любой директории запустить, можно путь относительно script.py задавать (см. ссылку вверху)

Comment: Так путь и задается из script.py относительно script.py

Comment: текущая рабочая директория и директория, где скрипт лежит не обязаны совпадать. Прочтите ссылку наверху

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path

myself = Path(__file__).resolve()
res = myself.parents[1] / 'resources.txt'

print('script.py :\t', myself)
print("directory :\t", myself.parents[0])
print("resources.txt :\t", res)
print("Contents:\n\n", res.open().read())
```

Результат:

```
script.py :      C:\Temp\.data\769835\mydir\script.py
directory :      C:\Temp\.data\769835\mydir
resources.txt :  C:\Temp\.data\769835\resources.txt
Contents:

 I'm [resources.txt] file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно при помощи модуля `os` прописать путь где находится ваш файл и открыть его

```
import os
path = 'C:\\test'
os.chdir(path)
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file:
    d = file.read()
    print(d)
```

---

Или так же можно в самом `open` прописать путь

```
with open('C:\\test/file1.txt', 'r') as file:
    d = file.read()
    print(d)
```

---

Так же можно используя [`path`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769835/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8/769887#comment1201332_769844) как предложил [@jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/23044/jfs), что является более правильным вариантом

```
from pathlib import Path
print(Path(r'c:\test\file1.txt').read_text())
```

Comment: чтобы текст по указанному пути из файла в строку прочитать в Питоне: `print(Path(r'c:\test\file.txt').read_text())` (+импорт: `from pathlib import Path`)¶ Не используйте os.chdir() без необходимости (это всё равно что  global использовать) — глобальные данные лучше не переопределять без уважительных причин.