# Как лучше сохранить дату последнего открытия программы?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как сделать, чтобы при запуске программы показывалась дата последнего ее запуска?Можно определить дату при помощи модуля `time` и сохранить в "Блокноте", а при запуске извлекать строку с датой. Может есть другие способы?

Comment: Реестр, например.

Comment: в python есть модуль для работы с реестром? Или он не нужен?

Comment: Есть модуль, да

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для переносимости и чтобы проще отлаживать, можно в человекочитаемом формате сохранять время:

```
import datetime as DT

print(DT.datetime.now(DT.timezone.utc))
# -> 2018-02-07 07:48:55.388757+00:00
```

Чтобы результат не зависел от [текущей рабочей директории](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535318/23044) (чтобы из любой директории можно было программу запустить), следует полный путь указать к файлу со временем.

Чтобы в общепринятое место пользовательские данные писать, [можно `appdirs` модуль использовать](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/appdirs) :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import datetime as DT
from pathlib import Path
import appdirs   # $ pip install appdirs

path = Path(appdirs.user_data_dir("Название программы", "Автор")) / 'last_run_time.txt'

# read time of the last program run if available 
if path.exists():
    last_run_time = DT.datetime.strptime(path.read_text(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f+00:00').replace(tzinfo=DT.timezone.utc)
    print(last_run_time.astimezone()) # display local time
else:  # first run
    path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)


# update time
now = DT.datetime.now(DT.timezone.utc)
path.write_text(now.isoformat(' '))
```

Comment: Отображается (и записывается) время отстающее на 3 часа. Почему так происходит (живу в Беларуси, время у нас полностью совпадает с московским)? Я убрал в предпоследней строке параметр `DT.timezone.utc`. Насколько я понял, это необязательный параметр tzinfo. Время записывается правильное, но в конце добавляются какие-то цифры; а отобразить через print не получается. Выдает ошибку: **ValueError: unconverted data remains: .569772**

Comment: @Франтишек: местное время может прыгать туда-сюда. Хранить следует время в UTC. Если вы это время где-то показываете (и хотите местное время показывать), то просто `print(last_run_time.astimezone())` вызовите (это за исключением крайних случаев местное время покажет). Убирать tzinfo не следует из `last_run_time`. Показывать можно конечно в любом формате (он не привязан к формату хранения).

Comment: Интересно почему оно "прыгает" на несколько часов?. Нельзя сделать чтобы было точное время?

Comment: @Франтишек: время точное уже. Под словом "прыгает" я имел ввиду переход с зимнего времени на летнее/перелёты на самолете (когда вы физически в другую часовую зону попадаете)/запустили на другом компьютере (который в другом месте может быть). Какие у вас проблемы с `print(last_run_time.astimezone())` кодом?

Comment: показывает время минус три часа. А если использовать класс today то нормальное. `now = DT.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f+00:00")  
path.write_text(now)`  Он будет показывать правильное время пользователя с другого часового пояса?

Comment: @Франтишек вы хотите сказать, что `print(last_run_time.astimezone())` показывает не ваше местное время? (обратите внимание `.astimezone()` вызов и это *единственное* изменение кода из ответа, если вы что-то ещё добавили, уберите) Или вы на время в файле смотрите, которое в другом часовом зоне указано?

Comment: в код приведенный вами выше добавил только одну сроку: `print(last_run_time.astimezone())`. Время в файле и в print одинаковое (только в конце строки час. пояса разные).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72911/discussion-between-jfs-and-).

Answer (score 4):

Думаю удобнее записав значение в файл. Работа с реестром будет довольно громоздкой, и возможно будет необходим запуск от имени администратора.

Вот вариант с записью в файл

```
import os, pickle, time

tmp_file = "test.pic"

if os.path.isfile(tmp_file):
    t = pickle.load(open(tmp_file, "rb"))
    print(t)
else:
    print("Time not found")

pickle.dump(str(time.time()), open(tmp_file, "wb"))
```