# Почему метод os.path.getatime не определяет время последнего доступа к файлу?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

Почему метод os.path.getatime не определяет время последнего доступа к файлу? Я запускаю нужный файл, закрываю. А скрипт определяет, что последний доступ к файлу был вчера. (ОС Windows)

```
import os
import time
path = 'my_file.py'
a = os.path.getatime(path)  # время последнего доступа
print(time.ctime(a))
```

Comment: О какой версии Windows идет речь?

Comment: Операц. система  Windows 7

Comment: если вы таким образом пытаетесь на [Как лучше сохранить дату последнего открытия программы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/780564/23044) вопрос ответить, то даже если `os.path.getatime()` верное время последнего доступа возвращает, это время может отличаться от последнего времени запуска (к примеру, антивирус может исполняемого файла коснуться, не запуская его).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В современных версиях Windows (7, 8, 10) `Last Access Time` отключен по умолчанию:

```
c:\>fsutil behavior query disablelastaccess
DisableLastAccess = 1
```

чтобы включить:

```
c:\>fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 0
NOTE: Changes to this setting require a reboot to take effect.
DisableLastAccess = 0
```

[NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959914.aspx) :

Description

> Determines whether NTFS updates the last-access timestamp on each
>   directory when it lists the directories on an NTFS volume.
>
> This entry is designed to prevent the NTFS log buffer in physical
>   memory from becoming filled with timestamp update records. If you have
>   an NTFS volume with a very large number of directories (in excess of
>   70,000), and Windows 2000 does not respond quickly to dir commands,
>   adding this entry to the registry might make directories list faster.

Comment: Думал это сисадмины прикрутили, а оно во как исторически сложилось.