# Сделать изображение квадратным на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения, обработка-изображений

Подскажите, как сделать с помощью Python изображение квадратным? Например, есть у меня изображение 800х600, получаю из него 800х800, недостающие пиксели заполняются каким-то цветом. 600х800 тоже превращается в 800х800. Желательно ещё центрировать, чтобы в итоговом изображение исходное находилось по центру. 
Я почти новичок в Python, так что буду благодарен за как можно более подробный ответ.

Comment: если вы новичок, то разбейте задачу на более мелкие шаги и отдельные Stack Overflow вопросы задайте. К примеру, "как прочитать размер изображения", "как создать изображение заданного размера", "как вставить одно изображение в другое", "как найти координаты, чтобы изображение по центру вставлялось", "как сохранить изображение в Питоне в X формате"

Comment: Если в общих чертах, то определить больше ли исходное изображение, чем 800х800. Если да, уменьшить с сохранением пропорций до 800 пикселей по наибольшей стороне. Создать пустое фоновое изображение 800х800. Вставить исходное изображение в центр фонового. Сохранить. Все эти операции можно выполнить с использованием библиотеки [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io) и простейших арифметических операций.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev про уменьшение, как я понял, речь в вопросе не идёт. К примеру, если на входе 20x1000 картинка, то результат это 1000x1000 картинка (решение это шаги из моего первого комментария).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def resize_img(file, new_file, max_size):
    img = Image.open(pic_adress+file)
    if img.size[1] > img.size[0]:
        height = max_size
        ratio = (height / float(img.size[1]))
        width = int((float(img.size[0]) * float(ratio)))
        img = img.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img.save(pic_adress+new_file)
    else:
        width = max_size
        ratio = (height / float(img.size[0]))
        height = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(ratio)))
        img = img.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img.save(pic_adress+new_file)

def white_board(img_adress, new_image_adress):
    img = Image.open(pic_adress+img_adress)
    white_img = Image.open(pic_adress+'white.jpg')

    x = int((white_img.size[0] - img.size[0])/2)
    y = int((white_img.size[1] - img.size[1])/2)

    white_img.paste(img,(x,y))
    white_img.save(pic_adress+new_image_adress)

resize_img('img.jpg','resized_img.jpg',600)
white_board('resized_img.jpg','new_image.jpg')
```

Сделал вот так.

Comment: Строчки         `img = img.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img.save(pic_adress+new_file)` можно вынести за пределы `if`, потому что они идентичные.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы вставить заданное изображение в квадрат, заполненный заданным цветом, со стороной не более заданной (если нужно уменьшив до его размеров исходное изображение перед вставкой, сохраняя пропорции):

```
from PIL import Image  # $ pip install pillow

def make_square(old_path, new_path, max_size=600, fill_color=(0, 0, 0)):
    # find image dimensions
    old_img = Image.open(old_path)
    size = (min(max_size, max(old_img.size)),) * 2

    # resize if old image is larger than max_size
    if size[0] < old_img.size[0] or size[1] < old_img.size[1]:
        old_img.thumbnail(size)

    # create new image with the given color and computed size
    new_img = Image.new(old_img.mode, size, fill_color)

    # find coordinates of upper-left corner to center the old image in the new image
    assert new_img.size[0] >= old_img.size[0]
    assert new_img.size[1] >= old_img.size[1]

    x = (new_img.size[0] - old_img.size[0]) // 2
    y = (new_img.size[1] - old_img.size[1]) // 2

    # paste image
    new_img.paste(old_img, (x, y))

    # save image
    new_img.save(new_path)
```

Пример, исходная картинка:

[image: moon10.jpg]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pathlib import Path
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

filename = 'moon10.jpg'
# old path is relative to the script # just an example
old_path = Path(__file__).parent.resolve() / filename
if not old_path.exists():
    urlretrieve('http://astro.unl.edu/misc/moonpics/' + filename, old_path)
# new path is relative to working dir
make_square(old_path, new_path='square_' + filename)
```

Скрипт закачивает [public domain] картинку (если она ещё не скачана) и кладёт рядом со скриптом. Затем создаётся квадратная картинка и сохраняется в текущую рабочую директорию. См. [Текущая директория в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535318/23044).

Результат, квадратная картинка:

[image: square_moon10.jpg]