# Какой метод в библиотеке PIL соединяет 2 картинки в одну?

Tags: python, pil

Помогите пожалуйста, недавно начал изучать библиотеку PIL в python
Не могу понять как из соединить 2 картинки в одну

Comment: Смотря как вы их "соединить" хотите.

Comment: пример: [одно изображение в другое помещается (paste)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/781039/23044)

Answer (score 2):

```
from PIL import Image

#выбираем файлы, которые будем объединять. 
#В моем случае google_images название подпапки, в которой хранятся изображения. 
#Двойной слеш для устранения проблемы кодировки.

img_file_1 = 'google_images\\51NV6IL6q7L._AC_SL1080_.jpg'
img_file_2 = 'google_images\\811RGQWpH5L._SL1500_.jpg'

#открываем файлы

im_1 = Image.open(img_file_1)
im_2 = Image.open(img_file_2)

#картинки разного размера, поэтому для соединения их нужно преобразовать в единых размер.
#Можно выбрать свой в зависимости от ориентирования "склеивания". 
#Я покажу пример склеивания по горизонтали. 

im_1 = im_1.resize((400, 400))
im_1.size
im_2 = im_2.resize((400, 400))
im_2.size

#создаём пустую картинку 

new_image = Image.new('RGB',(2*img_1.size[0], img_1.size[1]), (250,250,250))

#вставляем наши изображения

new_image.paste(img_1,(0,0))
new_image.paste(img_2,(mirrored_img_1.size[0],0))

#сохраняем новое объединенное изображение в нужном формате

new_image.save("some_image.jpg","JPEG")

#смотрим, что получилось 

new_image.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

The code you provided is an example of how to combine two images using the PIL (Python Imaging Library) module. However, there are a few errors and inconsistencies in the code. Here's the corrected version:

```py
from PIL import Image

# Select the image files to be merged
img_file_1 = 'google_images/51NV6IL6q7L._AC_SL1080_.jpg'
img_file_2 = 'google_images/811RGQWpH5L._SL1500_.jpg'

# Open the image files
im_1 = Image.open(img_file_1)
im_2 = Image.open(img_file_2)

# Resize the images to the same size
im_1 = im_1.resize((400, 400))
im_2 = im_2.resize((400, 400))

# Create a new image with double the width of the individual images
new_image = Image.new('RGB', (2 * im_1.size[0], im_1.size[1]), (250, 250, 250))

# Paste the images onto the new image
new_image.paste(im_1, (0, 0))
new_image.paste(im_2, (im_1.size[0], 0))

# Save the merged image in the desired format
new_image.save("some_image.jpg", "JPEG")

# Display the merged image
new_image.show()
```

In this corrected code:

1. The backslashes (`\`) in the file paths have been replaced with forward slashes (`/`) to ensure compatibility across different operating systems.
2. The image resizing code has been fixed to use the correct variable names (`im_1` and `im_2` instead of `img_1` and `img_2`).
3. The `mirrored_img_1` variable has been removed since it was not defined or necessary.
4. The `new_image.show()` command displays the merged image after saving.

Make sure you have the PIL module installed (`pip install pillow`) before running the code.

Comment: 1. переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык 2. [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)