# python не создает файл (json.dump)

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

почему то не работает вот этот код, не пойму.. должен работать

```
import json
numbers = [1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7]

file_name = 'numbers.json'
with open(file_name, 'w') as f_obj:
    json.dump(numbers, f_obj)
```

по идее должен создаться файл - numbers.json
но он не создается.
почему не пойму...

потом должен быть вот такой код считывающий данные 
import json

```
file_name = 'numbers.json'
with open(file_name) as f_obj:
    numbers = json.load(f_obg)
print(numbers)
```

но ничего нет так как нет файла - numbers.json
можете подсказать?

Comment: что значит не создается? вы пробовали указать полный путь к файлу?

Comment: то есть я его должен создать перед этим? я думал он создаться сам в этой строчке - with open(file_name, 'w'). ведь python сам создает файл если его нет этой командой? или я чего то не понимаю?:)

Comment: нет, укажите путь к файлу, например: `file_name = r'c:/temp/numbers.json'` И исправьте: `json.load(f_obg)` --> `json.load(f_obj)`

Comment: понял спасибо большое

Comment: если опечатку в коде поправить, то он работает. Какую вы точно ошибку получаете? Вы уверены, что это `FileNotFoundError` (не найден файл), а не `NameError: name 'f_obg' is not defined` (просто опечатка). Файл создаётся в текущей рабочей директории (может отличаться от папки с вашим скриптом) [Текущая директория в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535318/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы быть уверенным, что создаваемый файл будет записан в нужную директорию надо либо явно указать полный путь к файлу либо предварительно сменить текущую директорию.

```
file_name = r'c:/temp/numbers.json'
with open(file_name, 'w') as f_obj:
    json.dump(numbers, f_obj)
```

или

```
import os

...

os.chdir(r'c:/temp')

file_name = 'numbers.json'
with open(file_name, 'w') as f_obj:
    json.dump(numbers, f_obj)
```