# Экранировать символы "\" в python

Tags: python

Задача заключается в том, чтобы добавить строчку `\app.exe`,
но программа сопротивляется и считает это чем-то наподобие символа `\n`. Как экранировать обратный слеш, чтобы он считался строкой?

```
dir = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
dir = dir+"\app.exe"
file.write(dir)
comand = 'REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v Microsoft System /t REG_SZ /f /d ' + dir
os.system(comand)
```

Comment: Двойной слэш раскроется  \\ в \

Comment: Слеш в обратную сторону тоже помогает.

Answer (score 9):

"Сырые" строки - подавляют экранирование
Если перед открывающей кавычкой стоит символ 'r' (в любом регистре), то механизм экранирования отключается.

```
S = r'\app.exe'
```

Подробнее о работе со строками:
https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-literaly-strok.html

Comment: в `r''`-строках  `\a` заменяется на `\a` (для любого `а`), поэтому `r'\'` (строка с одиноким ``\``) не разрешена (если бы `r''`-строки *"подавляли"* экранирование, то можно было бы одинокий backslash использовать в `r''`-строках). То есть если нечётный backslash не последний символ в строке, то действительно можно думать, что "подавляет" экранирование.

Answer (score 6):

Воспользуйтесь [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) для путей в файловой системе:

```
import os

prg = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.curdir), 'app.exe')
comand = 'REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run" /v Microsoft System /t REG_SZ /f /d {}'.format(prg)
```

Путь к реестру тоже нужно заэкранировать как-то. Или через r'a\b' или 'а\b'.

Comment: полный путь из относительного пути лучше с помощью `os.path.abspath('app.exe')` создать. См. [Текущая директория в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535318/23044)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы полный путь получить из относительного пути:

```
app_path = os.path.abspath('app.exe')
```

См. [Текущая директория в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535318/23044).

---

Чтобы руками Windows-пути задавать:

```
app_path = r'C:\какой-то\путь\app.exe'
```

Если вы хотите в конце backslash добавить:

```
some_dir = r'C:\какой-то\путь' '\\'
```

`r''`-строки не могут на нечётное количество `\` заканчиваться, поэтому  в конце обычный string literal используется, в котором экранируется `\`. Оба типа string literal, отделённых пробелом сшиваются в одну строку.

---

Если вы хотите передать путь в `os.system()`, то может потребоваться экранировать специальные для `cmd.exe` символы (`%COMSPEC%`) такие как **пробелы**, `^`, итд в пути. [Why character '^' is ignored byt Python Popen - how to escape '^' character in Popen Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27864103/4279)

`reg.exe` не является внутренней командой, поэтому вы можете её напрямую запустить без `cmd.exe` с помощью `subprocess` модуля. Предполагая, что reg.exe следует правилам для разбора командной строки, [принятых для C программ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1y7w461.aspx), можно как список передать аргументы (не тестировано):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(['REG', 'ADD',
    r'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run',
    '/v', 'Microsoft System', '/t', 'REG_SZ', '/d', app_path, '/f'])
```

в этом случае параметры с **пробелами** автоматически в кавычки заключаются, когда из списка строка команды для `CreateProcess()` создаётся.

Правила по разбору командной строчки [не слишком просты и не полностью документированы](http://www.daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm#WINCRULESCHANGE), поэтому предпочтительней, чтобы автоматически командная строчка создавалась (чтобы в одном месте баги -- в `subprocess.list2cmdline()`). То есть передавайте аргументы в виде списка, если вы точно не знаете синтаксис командной строки, ожидаемый вызываемой программой.

---

Для работы с регистром вместо запуска внешней программы, [можно `winreg` модуль использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html).