# Проблема при конвертации jupyter notebook файла в исполняемый .py

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли конвертировать jupyter notebook файл .ipynb в .py. Я пытался это сделать средствами самого jupyter notebook: File-Export as-Executable script, но при запуске полученного скрипта через anaconda prompt получаю такую ошибку:

[image: ошибка]

Я в проекте использую библиотеку dlib, для распознавания лиц. Также в процессе работы программы подгружаются доп.

Файлы:

```
dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat
shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.
```

В чем может быть проблема?

P.S. Вообще целью этого всего процесса была возможность запуска скрипта отдельно от jupyter notebook enviroment, например через консоль. Если кто-то знает другие способы как это можно сделать - пожалуйста поделитесь.

Comment: У вас файл скорее всего находится в директории `"D:\KP\"`, а скрипт вы запускаете из другой директории. Для скрипта текущая директория - `"C:\Users\Alex1"`, там он и ищет файл с данными.

Comment: убедитесь, что `sys.executable` совпадают (тот же python используется) и та  же [текущая директория в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535318/23044).

Comment: при проверке sys.executable:
import sys
print(sys.executable)
выдает C:\Users\Alex1\Anaconda3\python.exe
Причем когда я все файлы проекта вынес в  C:\Users\Alex1>, т.е. базовый путь, то все заработало.

Comment: Все, все заработало) Спасибо за помощь!