# Как вытащить ошибки возвращаемые cmd(скрытой) python в файл.txt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, tkinter, пути

Когда в программе происходит какая-либо ошибка, нужно, чтоб при ошибке создавался файл с текстом который возвращает сам python в cmd.И сделать так, чтоб при любой ошибке программа закрывалась и говорила, "сохранить логи программы с кодом ошибки?"

Например:

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()
lab = Label(root, text="")
lab.pack()
def func(a,c):
    lab['text'] = str(a / c)

root.after(100,func=func(a,c))
root.mainloop()
```

В примере ошибка: NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: Последовательность: try/except (лучше sys.excepthook), модуль traceback, open. Если напишу вам предложенное выше без tk, сможете тот диалог с вопросом сами добавить? :)

Comment: Да наверное ...

Comment: чтобы облегчить контроль что куда идёт, logging модуль можно использовать (чтобы не только исключения, но и другие интересные события писать в файл и/или другие места). Связанный вопрос: [Logging uncaught exceptions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6234405/4279)

Comment: Второй вопрос создаю

Comment: [Второй вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/834881/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-cmd%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-python-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-txt2) @gil9red

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При запуске скрипта поищите в *текущей рабочей директории скрипта* файл `error.txt`:

```
import sys
import traceback

from tkinter import *


def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))
    print(text)

    # NOTE: Сюда добавить диалог TK, пример из PyQt
    # QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    with open('error.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(text)

    sys.exit()


sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions

root = Tk()
lab = Label(root, text="")
lab.pack()

def func(a, c):
    lab['text'] = str(a / c)

root.after(100,func=func(a, c))
root.after(150,func=func(10, 0))
root.mainloop()
```

---

- `sys.excepthook` используется для отлова исключений, что не были пойманы (try/except)
- `traceback.format_tb` используется, чтобы получить текст исключения и стек трассы (текст, что в консоли)
- Тут уточню, что относительные пути типа `error.txt` [работают относительно *текущей рабочей директории*](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535318/23044). Текущая директория не обязательно будет в папке со скриптом. А при записи (или считывании) файла без указания полного пути, будет поиск именно по в текущей рабочей директории. Например, если откроете консоль в корне диска C:/ и запустите из него скрипт на рабочем столе, то текущей рабочей директорией будет диск корень диска C:/. А чтобы сделать рабочей директорией рабочий стол, нужно было перейти в нее и из нее вызывать. Но это касается не только консоли, но и, например, в свойствах ярлыков есть указание где будет рабочая директория.
  Если нужно чтобы тот файл точно сохранялся в папке с скриптом, нужно сделать путь полным.

Доработка для сохранения в текущую папку с скриптом:

```
import os
file_name = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'error.txt')

with open(file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

- `os.path.dirname(__file__)` – вернет путь к текущей директории с файлом скрипта (этот вариант не предусматривает некоторые специфичные случаи, в отличии [от этого решения](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22881871/5909792))
- `os.path.join` – поможет правильно объединить путь к директории и файлу

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78150/discussion-on-answer-by-gil9red-----cmd-py).