# При исключении в tkinter не вызывается функция sys.excepthook

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, исключения

[Предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/834517/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-cmd%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-python-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-txt1)

Вот пример кода с ошибкой:

```
from tkinter import Tk, messagebox

def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    import traceback
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))
    print(text)
    if messagebox.askyesno("Неизвестная ошибка", "Сохранить лог с ошибкой?") == True:
        with open('error.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(text)
    raise SystemExit


import sys
sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions

root = Tk()

def m_geometry(win):
    #x = (win.winfo_screenwidth() / 2) - (295 / 2)
    y = (win.winfo_screenheight() / 2) - (395 / 2)
    root.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))

root.after(2000, lambda: m_geometry(root)) #Функция m_geometry(root) сработает через 2 секунды

root.mainloop()
```

Ошибка:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 746, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:/.../Error.py", line 27, in <lambda>
    root.after(2000, lambda: m_geometry(root))
  File "C:/.../Error.py", line 25, in m_geometry
    root.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Нужно чтоб было сообщение об выборе: сохранить лог или нет

Comment: Раскомментируйте `#x = `

Comment: Это я специально для примера

Comment: @оаавирыыва, теперь понял. Судя по всему, tk внутри себя обработал исключение и не дал упасть приложению, поэтому и не дошло до excepthook

Comment: И как это исправить?

Comment: Как сделать так, чтобы tk не обрабатывал внутри себя исключения, а посылал их дальше? Добавьте: `root.report_callback_exception = log_uncaught_exceptions` :)

Comment: не совсем так... tk есть строчка mainloop() это она не даёт скрипту рассыпатся окончательно. в первый раз она просто скажет что есть событие и только при закрытие окна скажет где именно. если ошибка повторится более одного раза тогда в шеле вы увидите где.

Comment: раскоментируйте x и всё у вас бедт работать. если нужно отлавливать события используйте конструкцию try

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Хук в `sys.excepthook` не срабатывал, из-за того что `tkinter` обрабатывал исключения в коллбэках, и чтобы появилась возможность самому обработать те исключения нужно использовать `root.report_callback_exception`:

```
import traceback
import sys

from tkinter import Tk, messagebox


def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))
    print(text)

    # Если Yes, сохраняем ошибку в файл
    if messagebox.askyesno("Неизвестная ошибка", "Сохранить лог с ошибкой?"):
        with open('error.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(text)
    
    sys.exit()


sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions

root = Tk()
root.report_callback_exception = log_uncaught_exceptions

def m_geometry(win):
    #x = (win.winfo_screenwidth() / 2) - (295 / 2)
    y = (win.winfo_screenheight() / 2) - (395 / 2)
    root.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))

# Функция m_geometry(root) сработает через 2 секунды
root.after(2000, lambda: m_geometry(root))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Все работает, спасибо большое :)