# Помогите правильно настроить пути в Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

В общем пайчарм через импорт не видит файлы. Препод говорит, что проблема в путях.

Сказать честно я не сильно в этом разбираюсь, но что-то понастраивал. Файлы и папки он опять же видит криво.

Пример: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, например, мне нужно импортировать тот класс в файл, что в картинке, но он его не видит и папку  TOOLS находит подсвечивает только через ... точки (три точки)

Сорян если вопрос немного глупый, я просто не совсем пойму, что не так настроено. Или в чем еще может быть проблема.

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm не анализирует весь ваш проект чтобы найти `tools` и зарезолвить `from tools` импорт - он ищет `tools` только в тех директориях, которые (по его мнению) окажутся в `PYTHONPATH` в рантайме.

Когда вы запускаете `app.py` из папки `Program` последняя добавляется в `PYTHONPATH` в результате чего Python в состоянии найти `tools`, что объясняет почему оно работает при запуске.

IDE, к сожалению, не знает наперед какие файлы вы будете запускать руками и не пытается добавлять все возможные директории в `PYTHONPATH` иначе был бы полный хаос в комплишене.

Тем не менее, IDE можно дать знать что директория должна присутствовать в `PYTHONPATH` кликнув правой кнопкой мыши по папке в дереве проекта (в нашем случае `Program`) и выбрав **Mark directory as -> Source Root**.

Иконка папки будет подсвечена синим. `from tools` должен рарезолвится.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте что вам вернет current_dir.
Если папку проекта, то путь надо будет писать полный, или cd \current_dir\Lesson 17(Import) -  когда она должна стать текущей и импорт должен отрабатывать.

Comment: извините, а Вы бы могли наглядно показать как это сделать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535318/Текущая-директория-в-python